# ruby prawn how to wrap text around an aligned right image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn, prawnto

s it posible to align an image to the right and wrap text around the image like it is in html and css using the float:right property ?

If so how do you do this ?

I can align an image but dont't know how to wrap the text around it.  The text is dynamic text therefore varies alot in length.

Thanks alot
Rick

Comment: Richard, you've asked eight questions and haven't accepted any answers yet. If an answer has helped you then please click on the tick on the left underneath the number of votes the answer has received. Thanks!

Comment: John i have accepted some answers that helped me, didnt know i had to do that cheers rick

Comment: Select a accepted answer if it was the answer to you question, not if it merely pointed you in the right direction. In that case you can submit an answer yourself and select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion is to try nested bounding boxes.  The main bounding box would have the text inside it. with at some point another bounding box for the image.  Something along the lines of

```
bounding_box([x,y], :width => bounds.width, :height => 400) do
    text "blah"
    text "blah"
    # image
    bounding_box([bounds.right - image_width, 0], :width => image_width) do
          image("path_to_file", :at => [0,0], :width =>  bounds)
    text "more blah"


end
```

You may be able to simply use the image without the bounding box, but the bounding box would ensure that the text flows around it.

Comment: at least for me this did not work... text was still written over the image

Comment: This does not work.  Text flows right over the top of another bounding box.